# Initialize rbenv and run ruby script from shell script

Tags: ruby, shell, svn-hooks, rbenv

Initialize rbenv and run ruby script from shell script

I want svnserve to run pre-commit hook, written on ruby. As the svnserve is run as root user, it knows nothing about user rbenv installation.

I set a soft link /usr/bin/ruby -> /home/admin/.rbenv/shims/ruby .
As result, when i try

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
puts "Pre-commit hook!"
```

It shows error:

```
Transmitting file data .svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Commit blocked by pre-commit hook (exit code 255) with no output.
```

When i run manually on Server:

```
admin $ sudo ./pre-commit
/usr/bin/ruby: line 4: exec: rbenv: not found
```

So, i suppose, that rbenv initialization is needed, but how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In hooks path:

pre-commit:

```
#!/bin/bash
export HOME=/home/user
if [ -d $HOME/.rbenv ]; then
  export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$PATH"
  eval "$(rbenv init -)"
fi
$0.rb $*
```

pre-commit.rb:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
ARGV.each_with_index { |arg, index| puts "Index #{index}: Argument #{arg}" }
```

Comment: Current versions of rbenv use `$HOME/.rbenv/shims` instead of `$HOME/.rbenv/bin`. Otherwise sadfuzzy's script is still good.

Answer (score 2):

you should initialize `rbenv` before using it.

```
/path/to/user/home/.rbenv/bin/rbenv init
```

then set ruby version globally:

```
rbenv global DESIRED-RUBY-VERSION
```

or localy:

```
rbenv local DESIRED-RUBY-VERSION
```

or per shell:

```
rbenv shell DESIRED-RUBY-VERSION
```

though not sure shell setting will work without a tty.

so you could create a shell script, `pre-commit.sh` and register it as a svn hook.

inside it initialize `rbenv` and call your `pre-commit.rb` file

Comment: Well, i know :) but how it can be done in one script (it is called by subversion)?

Comment: i guess your hook should be a shell script that firstly initialize `rbenv` then call a ruby script?

Comment: You are completely right! I want to initialize and run ruby code from the script.

Comment: +1 for this. I had a similar issue and ended up by creating 2 scripts - `hook.sh` that initializes `rbenv` and call my second script - `hook.rb`

Comment: How should i pass params into ruby script from pre-commit hookm which will initialize rbenv?

Comment: @sadfuzzy, how does your params looks? you could pass them as arguments - `pre-commit.rb "arg1" "arg2" "etc"` and read them by `$*` in your ruby script. please note quotes around args, they are used to handle the case when your args contains spaces

Comment: Thanks! I've found this yet. Here is the solution: 
pre-commit:
`#!/bin/bash
export HOME=/home/user
if [ -d $HOME/.rbenv ]; then
  export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
  eval "$(rbenv init -)"
fi
$0.rb $*`

pre-commit.rb:
`#!/usr/bin/env ruby
ARGV.each_with_index { |arg, index| puts "Index #{index}: Argument #{arg}" }
`